# IntelliJ Spring MVC tutorial deployment

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea

I tried the [tutorial](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Getting+Started+with+Spring+MVC,+Hibernate+and+JSON) and when I tried to deploy the webapp(`IntelliJ 13.1.4 Ultimate`), i got an weird error as shown in the screenshot below. What is the resolution for this error?

> `org.jdom.input.JDOMParseException: Error on line 742: The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.`

[Complete error](http://pastebin.com/1PLdxr2k)

[image: parseException]

Comment: If you add the files somewhere so I can have a look at them I will probably find the error :D

Comment: I have added the code here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0NJuNGnNU9yTm5nZnZIbGxJa00/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Can you take a look at your xml files? The error indicates that your xml is not well-formed and thus it can be parsed correctly. Maybe you can use something like

http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have any apparent errors in your files (marked with a red underline in IntelliJ) then you can do "Invalidate Caches and restart"

1. Goto settings (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>)
2. Select "Invalidate Caches / Restart"
3. Select "Invalidate and restart"

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Tried it but still same error

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you forgot:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

at the top of your .jsp...?

The error might also arise if you have invalid HTML, for example:

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

will cause that exception in some cases.

Comment: the top of the page has <!doctype html>

Answer (score 0):

This was a real pain. I had to remove .idea folder and re-add one by one the contents back in. My problem was in the workspace.xml (dont know what it was) but I guess it could be any of the xml files. I just let it create a new one and all good.